# tengo problema al ejecutar las "opciones" de sidenav de materializecss

Tags: javascript, materialize

Quiero ejecutar el side nav al cargar la página, según la documentación de materialize se puede ejecutando la función onOpenStart, pero no logró que funcione.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var elem = document.querySelector('.sidenav');
      var instance = M.Sidenav.init(elem, {
      onOpenStart: function ()
      }
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49756930/5215609

Comment: Claramente antes de escribir la pregunta consulté, y esa respuesta no me ayudó.

Comment: @AndrésCárdenas deberías de incluir tu HTML para tener un [mcve]